# Recommended Approach for Mapping 12 Types to a Single ViewModel in 4 Different Ways?

Tags: c#, viewmodel, dry

I'm trying to use a single view model to display various item types as links on a page. For example TeamMembers, NewsItems, Articles etc.

I have 4 x item>VM mappings that cover 12 item types.  (For example the subtitle for NewsItems will be publish date, for  TeamMembers it will be their position in the company.)

*I'm considering 3 options, but none of them feel very elegant to me.  Would anyone with more experience be able to guide me in the right direction?*

**The ViewModel**

```
public class ItemLink
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class LinkSet
{
    public List<ItemLink> Links {get;set;}

    public LinkSet(IEnumerable<NewsOrArticlesOrTeamMembers>, myEumerable)
    {
        // mapping here 
    }
}
```

**Option 1**

Create a constructor for each item type. That would give me 12 constructors for 4 sets of mappings, which doesn't seem very DRY.

**Option 2**

Create an Item > VM mapping class with the 3 options. Choose which option to use when instantiating the VM.  This feels like it's introducing unnecessary complexity into the application.

**Option 3***

Give the VM constructor of the a dynamic argument, test for type inside the constructor and choose the appropriate mapping accordingly. This would be my only use of Reflection in the whole application, so I'd rather not use it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, one way to go would be to introduce an interface like the following:

```
interface IItemLinkProvider
{
     string GetTitle();
     string GetSubtitle();
     string GetImage();
}
```

You can implement this interface with all the classes you'd like to support. Thus you can modify the constructor of your LinkSet like this:

```
public class LinkSet
{
    public List<ItemLink> Links { get; set; }

    public LinkSet(IEnumerable<IItemLinkProvider> items)
    {
        Links = items.Select(i => new ItemLink
            {
                Title = i.GetTitle(),
                Subtitle= i.GetSubtitle(),
                Image = i.GetImage()
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

This way you can decouple your LinkSet view model from the concrete model types, and can make it only depend on the abstraction (the `IItemLinkProvider` interface), which is always a good thing.

(Note that you are going to need C# 4.0 to use this constructor properly because covariance of generic interfaces has been introduced in C# 4.0)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for taking the time to answer.  As I understand it that would be the equivalent of option 2, but maybe a more elegant way of doing it?  And would each of my data models then require the methods specified on the interface?  I'm pretty new to c#, got a fair bit to learn.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to that, but maybe a bit more elegant because it does not involve introducing another class, just creating an interface for the existing classes. Yes, each model class would have to have the specified methods. (By the way, the interface can contain properties with a getter instead of methods, if it fits your style better.)

Comment: By the time I see this it has been successfully implemented. Thanks a lot for your help :-)